# How to append HTML after a textarea in jquery?

Tags: jquery, textarea

I want to append some html **after** (not within) a `textarea`

i.e. change

```
<textarea>content</textarea>
```

to

`<textarea>content</textarea>other_content`

I can append to a header or a div but when I try to use a textarea it doesn't do it.  Why?

HTML

```
<h1>Top</h1>
<h2> middle</h2>
<textarea>stuff</textarea>
<h3> h3</h3>
```

JS

```
var a=10;
var b=20;
var c=a+b*20;
$("textarea").append( $( "<h2>-z-z-</h2>" ) ); // doesn't work
$('textarea').val('the result ' + c); // works but I want the content after the tag, not in the textarea
$("h3").append( $( "<h2>-x-x-</h2>" ) );  // works on h3 element
```

Comment: Text area is basically an input element. So it is not possible to set using `append()`. You need `val()` for that. The element does have an open and close tags, but the innter value is not treated as markup.

Comment: _"I want the content after the tag but in the textarea"_ uh, what?

Comment: typo fixed that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("textarea").after("<h2>-x-x-</h2>");
```

Comment: Yes that worked.  thanks!  Do you know why I had the issue with append but just for textarea?

Comment: because the textarea is an input element:so you can't put inside it an html tag, but you can only set a text with val()